# 'webdriver-manager start' command is not working in command terminal

Tags: node.js, proxy, protractor, webdriver-manager

When executing 'webdriver-manager start' for protractor, the below error is thrown,

[11:34:53] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined

[11:34:53] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

I am trying to use protractor from my office PC, so there maybe some proxy issue.I didn't face this issue when I tried with my personal laptop.please give some suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Install JDK. For me also, the same issue was there and got solved by installing JDK

Comment: I already have java installed.java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Do you have added `"C:\Windows\System32"` in your PATHs?. On windows, right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> Edit... PATH and add "C:\Windows\System32" to the end (with a semi-colon separating each variable).

Comment: Confirm you install JDK 8, ranther than JRE.  And even you installed JDK, make sure you expand the `JDK Home/bin`  to PATH,  rather than `JDK Home/jre/bin`. Meanwhile make sure the  `JDK Home/bin` will be first one in PATH